# Input:focus outline, but without blur effect

Tags: html, css, border

i want to have a 1px border on my input fields when they are focused, but without the blur effect.

i add the border with `outline-color..`  but how can i delete the blur effect?

`Border-radius:0px; and box-shaddow:0px;` don't solve the problem.

thanks

Comment: use input:focus{outline:none;} border-radius:0px; box-shadow:0px; box shaddow spelling mistake.

Comment: To remove the shadow is `box-shaddow:none`, not `0px` (even if I think it's not enough to fix your issue).

Comment: thats true, i made the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

okay Matthias M,

try this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" class="a">
<style>
.a:focus
{ 
border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a shadow (one for every side) without the `blur` parameter, like:

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px, -2px -2px;
```

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/QbY3C/471/) the Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{
border: solid 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. To add a border don't solve the problem. Also when i try to do something with box-shaddow. The key was to change the outline-style!  too easy :)

```
outline-width: 2px; outline-style: solid;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your css:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```

Or

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```